# Where I should add property that mainly is used in View, in Entity object or in Wrapper class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

`Product Entity` object is passed to the View. I want to add some properties that mainly concerns only the View like

```
public string MiddleImage
{
   get
   {
      return "M" + this.ImageUrl;
   }
}
```

And now I can use this property in the View

```
<img src="<%=Model.MiddleImage%>" />
```

My question is where I should add this property, in the Product Entity object itself or it's better to create another class that inherits from `Product`?

```
public class ProductWrapper : Product
{
    public string MiddleImage
    {
       get
       {
          return "M" + this.ImageUrl;               
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a `ProductViewModel` class that holds the properties that only your view cares about which of course can include any newly formed UI properties such as your image url.

Then save yourself some leg work and use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) in your controller to map those properties from the entity to the View Model.

Assign the view model's custom properties after the map.

Your `Product` entity maps to your persistence store, your `ProductViewModel` maps to your User Interface - exactly the separation of concerns MVC is trying to achieve.

Comment: So what you say is if I have 10 properties in `Product` class and I want to add another five, so it's better to create `ProductViewModel` class that will contain the **same 10 properties** from `Product` and the new 5 properties? Is this practical?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't be polluting my domain model with UI concerns. If your view needs every property in Product then have a view with the product as a property.